# how to add an interstitial page to prompt a user to enter a password before seeing Page#Show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

right now my app has a Pages model. Anyone with the url, /pages/3 can view a page. I want to make makes have the option of public or private.

- If public anyone with the URL can view.
- If the page if private, only users that enter a password should be able to view the page.

Right now the page is rendered with the Page#Show controller. What's the right way to go about handling this so that when a user tries to access a private page they first need to enter a password correctly and then they can view the page? How would I structure this in the controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using cancan:

```
def show
  @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  authorize! :read, @page
end
```

This will raise a `CanCan::AccessDenied` error (if the user isn't logged in or isn't authorized), which can be caught like so ([docs](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    # Save the requested path in the user's session
    session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
    # Send the user to the sign in page
    redirect_to sign_in_path, :alert => exception.message
  end
end
```

Depending on your authentication system, on a successful sign-in, in your sessions controller you can:

```
redirect_to session[:return_to] || your_default_after_sign_in_path
# Clear the :return_to value
session[:return_to] = nil
```

I may be missing some details, but this is the gist of it. Best of luck.

**EDIT**:
I should attribute the friendly forwarding part of my answer to [Michael Hartl and his book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec%3afriendly_forwarding).

Comment: Thanks Danny, but the user will have been signed in, no need to sign in, so I'm not sure if this solved the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need an authorization solution. I recommend [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) its pretty flexible. You can probably tweak it to use "Pages" as the resource that you "login" to instead of the standard "users" if you don't already have authentication and/or don't want authentication per user.

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently using CanCan, but I don't understand how that would solve for using an interstitial enter the page password view if the page is private?